# Fail to copying file in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

For copy file i use (code below) its **work properly**.

```
Section "one"
  CreateDirectory $EXEDIR\dst
  CopyFiles $EXEDIR\*.* $EXEDIR/dst
SectionEnd
```

When i use $PROGRAMFILES(only change the destination path) it create directory but copy **doesn't work**.

```
Section "two"
  CreateDirectory $PROGRAMFILES\dst
  CopyFiles $EXEDIR\*.* $PROGRAMFILES/dst
SectionEnd
```

where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you running the installer elevated as an Administrator?

Comment: yes but same output. @Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` is not the path separator on Windows, use `\`. `/` is supported in a lot of places but not everywhere.

It might also be failing if you don't have write access to that folder so make sure you have `RequestExectionLevel Admin` in your script.

The only way to know for sure is to monitor the installer with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)...

Comment: thanks.. it works by changing separator. one question if  it have not  write access, why create folder?

Comment: You could have the right to create a directory but not files. I don't know anything about your system so I just had to guess.

Comment: CopyFiles internally uses a old shell function which is probably why it cannot handle /.